# How to securely connect to a database with PHP?

Tags: php, databases, mysql, permissions

Currently in PHP (in the file `/var/www/website.com/public_html/functions.php`). I am connecting to the database like this:

```
function connect(){
    $config = parse_ini_file('/var/www/website.com/db.ini');
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost",$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['db']);
    if(!$con){
        die("Failed to connect to Database"); 
    }
    return $con;
}
```

Where the `/var/www/website.com/db.ini` is

```
username=user123
password=pass123
db=mydb
```

with permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 84 /var/www/website.com/db.ini
```

The PHP will be run by either `www-data` or `root`.

The root of `website.com` is `/var/www/website.com/public_html/`.

Is this the best way to connect to a database using PHP from a security point of view? I am also making this code open source.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what "secure" means in this context. Secure in what way? To store passwords in an .ini file? What threats are you worried about?

Comment: As an aside, I would definitely recommend against running the php code as `root`. I would also think you could probably get by with a -r--r--r-- (444) permission as opposed to -rw-r--r-- (644).

Comment: You can chgrp the credentials file to www-data and chmod it to 640 or 440.

Comment: If you run it using `www-data`, permissions are not right for the db config file. Any specific reason to run it as root?

Comment: Since presumably they'll only be *reading* the config, they can do so as www-data. The problem is that any other user can as well.

Comment: Are you merely making this open-source, or is this a project that you're actually anticipating many people using? That is, can you depend on some other infrastructure, or does it need to be easy to set up?

Comment: @DKNUCKLES You can't revoke writing right from root this way.

Comment: @Arminius I am aware of that fact. My advice was to *not* run as root, and set more strict permissions to the .ini file so I'm not sure where your comment is coming from?

Comment: @DKNUCKLES You're suggesting changing 644 to 444 for a root-owned file. What would that accomplish as root can write to it anyways?

Comment: @Arminius disable the web application from being able to write to it. Presumably a super user sets up the .ini file with the connection details which only need to be read and chown's it to to the web server user (www-user for instance), so the owner (www-user) does not need the ability to write to that file. This advice is obviously only relevant if the web application is not running as root as I had previously suggested.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES In the current case the config file is evidently owned by `root`.

Comment: @Arminius yes but again, as stated in my original comment i said to NOT run as root and change the permissions to 444.

Comment: @Arminius It's not the web application we should worry about, include files should not be reachable(!) from the web,and end users will never see PHP.  We worry more about our own (non priv'd) developers reading the credentials, or other ways (tty, shell) in. In fact, the development credentials will not be the same as production, and in this case do not include the server (localhost).  It is also desirable to consider multiple possible connections?

Comment: How about a SSL connection to the SQL server, if the network inbetween can be eye dropped? Also watchout that `www` is not any part of Apache host: I've already seen servers where `www.website.com` points to the directory you said, and `user.hosting-service.com` points to the `www` directory (or calling the server by it's IPv4 or IPv6) hence I would store ini outside any www directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach looks good.

- You are storing the credentials in a separate configuration file instead of having them written inline in the source code. This makes it safe when sharing the code with others and protects the credentials in case a misconfiguration lets the plain PHP code be printed out (which happens quite often).
- The config file is outside the public document root, therefore it cannot be directly accessed by a user of the web application, unless there is another vulnerability (e.g. a directory traversal flaw).
- In any case you should avoid running the server as `root`. Otherwise the permission model is worthless, since `root` can read and write to any file.

Note that you don't have to deal with parsing the credentials in your code at all - you can instead specify them as [PHP runtime settings](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.default-user) in the server configuration, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176831/5765873).

Also see:

- [How do I make my database connection secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345773/how-do-i-make-my-database-connection-secure)
- [How to secure database passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php)

Comment: The file does not have minimal permissions.  It could be chgrp'ed to www-data and chmod'ed 640.

Comment: I would go further than saying "you should avoid". You should **never** run a web server as root. It should run as its own user, and this is the default for most (if not all) package-based installations.

Answer (score 0):

I am skeptical of this `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root` approach. The secure way to do it would be

1. Make the file `-r-------- 1 root root` i.e. readable only by user `root`
2. Start your app as `root`, read the credentials and connect then immediately `setuid()` to `www-data`. So anyone who compromises the app *cannot* read the file, even via a directory traversal attack, unless of course they find another means of obtaining `root` in which case it's game over anyway. This [should be possible in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setuid.php).

This is the same mechanism web servers use to bind to port 80, which is a privileged port.